# Child class: *this = function_which_returns_parent_object(), is it possible?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to create a child class which behaves almost the same as the parent class.
The only difference is that the child has some extra methods.

```
Parent getParentObject()
{
    return Parent(123);
}

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(int a) : a(a)
    {}

    int a = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child()
    {
        *this = getParentObject();
    }
};
```

**Is that possible?**

Comment: You mean `*this = getParentObject()`? That's legal C++ but it completely unnecessary because a child object gets all it's parent's data anyway. You don't have to do anything special to make a child object behave the same as it's parent object, it happens anyway.

Comment: That's the same as `*this = Parent()` and accomplishes nothing beyond what the initialisation of the base has already done.

Comment: ... or are you looking for a way to convert an existing `Parent` instance into a `Child`?

Comment: @john yes, edited. There's a function from a library which upon called returns an object of in this case type `Parent` with data, and I don't want my class (in this case `Child`) to store a parent variable `Parent parent`.

Comment: It's edited now so that `getParentObject()` returns a `Parent` object with some not-default data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
 *this = getParentObject();
```

is possible only if assignment of `Parent` to `Child` is possible per class definition. You have to have `operator=` defined or a copy constructor if you go with `static_cast`.

But definition of `Child()` is ill-formed, because Parent got no default ctor.

```
Child() // <-- no initialization list, all sub-object are default-initialized
{
    *this = getParentObject();
}
```

All subobjects are default-initialized, and base class is always a subobject of derived class. Compiler-defined constructors in `Parent` are deleted because user had defined a custom constructor.

Whole bunch of requirements above can be omitted by

```
Child() : Parent(123) {}
```

or define copy\move constructor for `Parent` and use

```
Child() : Parent(getParentObject())
```

if you require such.

Comment: The top sentence helped me, since I can't assign during construction. My code example was bad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, but in this case it's not required. You can do this in an initializer list:

```
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child():Parent()
    {

    }
};
```

If the Parent only has a constructors with arguments, it is required to do this to initalize the Parent. Arguments can go inside the constructor call, and you can also use variables declared in the Child constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a copy constructor for your parent class, then simply this

```
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child(const Parent& parent) : Parent(parent)
    {
    }
};

Child c = getParentObject();
```

or this (which is more similar to your example)

```
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child() : Parent(getParentObject())
    {
    }
};

Child c;
```